# Iterate through 2 objects and 1 nested object in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following structure:

```java
class Object1 {
   String id;
   Integer total;
}
```

```java
class Object2 {
   String id;
   List<Object3> list;
}
```

```java
class Object3 {
   Integer total;
}
```

When `Object1` and `Object2` have the same `id` I need to update the `total` from Object1 by summing up the `total` from all the `Object3` within the `list` inside `Object2` and subtracting from `Object1` `total`.

It works like this without Java 8:

```java
for (Object1 object1 : list1) {
     for (Object2 object2 : list2) {
          if (object1.getId().equals(object2.getId())) {
              int total = 0;
              for (Object3 object3 : object2.getlist3()) {
                   total += object3.getTotal();
              }
              object1.setTotal(object1.getTotal() - total);
          }
     }
}
```

This is what I have so far using Java 8:

```java
list1.forEach(object1 -> list2.stream()
     .filter(object2 ->object2.getId().equals(object1.getId()))
```

But I don't know how to proceed with the logic because I am not very familiar with Java 8.

Comment: Keep it without the streams, it is much clearer for your case.

Comment: I agree with you, but there's no option other than using Java 8 in my case.

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes why not? the first will still work?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz See my answer. I prefer the functional style. It is both more expressive and shorter.

Comment: @HamishD, it was requested to me to use Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Explanations are inline as comments

```
list1.forEach(object1 -> 
    object1.setTotal(
        object1.getTotal() - list2.stream()
            .filter(object2 -> object1.getId().equals(object2.getId()))
            .flatMap(object2 -> object2.getList3().stream()) // Stream<Object2> to Stream<Object3>
            .mapToInt(Object3::getTotal)                     // get each total
            .sum()                                           // sum them
    )
);
```

It is worth noting that you are calling `object1.setTotal` multiple times if more than one ID matches, effectively overriding the previous result. You may say that this is fine, and that the lists are populated in a such a way that there will only be one matching ID. In which case, you should add a `break` statement after `object1.setTotal`. This will avoid iterating over the remaining elements in `list2` unnecessarily. A similar performance enhancement in a stream would require a significant change to the above example.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! i just had to put `object1.getTotal() -` before `list2.stream()`.

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes Sorry, I missed that aspect of your original code. Sure, happy to help